# Where do i learn credit card fraud detection with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Can anyone suggest me a good source to learn?

I am a newbie in ML

As I am a newbie, I have not done anything in this.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud) might be an excellent place to start. You can create a new kernel straight from the dataset page, and the data will be ready for you when you enter the kernel. You can also look at [other people's kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud/kernels) who have used that dataset, and I bet you'll find plenty of helpful examples.

You'll get lots of hate for asking this kind of question, since it doesn't fit in S.O. question parameters, but I prefer to be a useful human.